# PDF to XML: Any alternative to PDFX which can provide element tags info as well?

Tags: javascript, php, pdf, extract, data-extraction

I want to know if there is any open source solution (PHP Classes or Javascript maybe), which can extract the same information as [PDFX](http://pdfx.cs.man.ac.uk/usage):

The elements that PDFX can currently extract are:

**Front Matter**

title, abstract, author, author footnote

**Body Matter**

body text, h1, h2, h3, image, table, figure/table caption, figure/table reference, bibliographic item, bibliographic reference (citation)

**Extras**

header, footer, side note, page number, email, URI

**Note:-**

I am not interested in generating any PDF document by using FPDF or TCPDF etc.

I am interested in extracting content like all H1 tags, all H2 tag etc.

Comment: *"PDFX is not working"* - in which way? Do you have problems interacting with its interface or does it not extract your pdfs in a satisfactory manner?

Comment: Hi mkl ! it uses curl service to convert pdf into xml, but from last couple of days, this results in "Internal Server Error". No matter, if you do it via online UI or try it with it's PHP class